# Howto access the user's MKAnnotationView on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin) tutorial, I added a renderer for a `CustomMap` to my Xamarin.Forms iOS project. I would like to overwrite the basic `Pin` with the pin of the user's current location (i.e. the white/blue circle). So I added a class `CustomMapRenderer`, which overrides the method `GetViewForAnnotation` as follows

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var customPin = getTrackPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Id.ToString());
        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new TrackMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Id.ToString());
            annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
            annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
            annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
            ((TrackMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Id = customPin.Id.ToString();
            ((TrackMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.url;
        }
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
    }
```

However, instead of doing

```
annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
```

I would like to get the `UIImage` of the pin representing the user's current location, like so (pseudo-code):

```
annotationView.Image = UIImage.UserPin;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: As far as I know Apple doesn't make that annoatarion view class available. You would need to create your own implementation

Comment: Could I call `base.GetViewForAnnotation()` and pass a pretended `MKUserLocation` in order to get to that particular `MKAnnotationView` object? If yes, how can I create that `MKUserLocation` object?

Answer (score 0):

When you check if the annotation is MKUserLocation, remove return null.

Instead of returning null, configure your annotation

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    pin.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    return pin // 1

}
```

1. Return your pin

Comment: Maybe I haven't described my problem specific enough. It's actually the other way around. I want to replace the `AnnotationView`s of all the other pins (i.e. landmarks, for instance) with the one of the user's current location. Everything should have the same view that the user's current location has.